# Is there actually a language called "standard SQL", or am I being hoodwinked?

Tags: sql, resources

I'm taking a course from learnsql.com and asked which variant of SQL the course is written in (the course uses an online SQL terminal). The course did not mention this, which made it difficult to look up documentation. Here is their reply:

```
Hi,

The type you are learning is what we call 'standard SQL'. This is not a specific dialect, 
but includes the broadest range of features across all dialects to give you the most 
versatile possible grounding in the language.
​
I hope this has helped to answer your enquiry.
```

Does such a thing exist?

Comment: Standard SQL definitely exists.  It is observed by the deviation of all known databases from the standard.

Comment: They said in their message its not a specific dialect and just what they call standard sql. What they mean  by that is its features that can be found in most SQL versions.

Comment: It would be difficult to know exactly what they mean.  They probably mean they are teaching ANSI SQL.  Maybe the RDBMS they are using has a configuration setting that enables them to disable all of the non-ANSI features.

Answer (score 0):

Common in all systems.
Tips：Non-standard SQL function, that web will explain famous system  (Microsoft SQL Server or mysql

[Mysql](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_ref_mysql.asp) or
[Microsoft SQL Server](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_ref_msaccess.asp)

Comment: OP didn't say anything about MySQL or MariaDB.  And I don't see the PS special command in the documentation you provided.  When I create a query on DBFiddle (https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=6bc7e2f849c8ddf426e2b15cc4c3e28d) for MySQL 5.6, I get an error.  What are you talking about?

Comment: PS = postscript

Comment: I still don't see how MySQL or MariaDB relates to the question.

Comment: All systems will independently produce some functions of their own,example:mysql=>ASCII(),MS server=>Asc()

Comment: My fault,These two examples is too Close.

Comment: I just want to explain, non-standard SQL function,Sorry,I say so inarticulate